# Websphere MQ: How to use SSL with Managed Client

Tags: ssl, websphere, ibm-mq

I'm using `IBMMQDotnetClient` (v9.2.0) to connect `Webphere MQ` (v9.1.0.3). This server required SSL to connect. I have tried but faced the error 2538. I have developed a test tool in .Net FW (use MQ lib for .Net FW) and used `Unmanaged Mode` and it connected to that server successful.
I found this information from IBM documentation:

From: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q029470_.htm

```
When WebSphere® MQ classes for .NET are used as a managed client,
there are a number of differences from a standard WebSphere MQ MQI
client.
The following features are not available to a managed client: 
- Channel compression  
- SSL support  
- Channel exit chaining
```

--> That means `Managed Client` not support SSL (?)

From: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_9.1.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q132490_.htm

```
IBM MQ classes for .NET Standard only support `Managed Client`
```

--> That means `IBMMQDotnetClient` only support `Managed Client`

Summary: With `IBMMQDotnetClient` I can only use `Managed Client` and `Managed Client` does not support SSL. Am I correct? How can I use `IBMMQDotnetClient` with SSL?

This is my code, it throw error 2538: MQRC_HOST_NOT_AVAILABLE:

```
var sslQueueProperties = new Hashtable
                {
                    [MQC.HOST_NAME_PROPERTY] = mqHostName,
                    [MQC.PORT_PROPERTY] = mqPort,
                    [MQC.CHANNEL_PROPERTY] = mqChannelName,
                    [MQC.USER_ID_PROPERTY] = mqUserName,
                    [MQC.PASSWORD_PROPERTY] = mqPassword,
                    [MQC.SSL_CERT_STORE_PROPERTY] = certStore,
                    [MQC.SSL_CIPHER_SPEC_PROPERTY] = cipherSpecProperty,
                    [MQC.TRANSPORT_PROPERTY] = MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_MANAGED
                };
                
_mQQueueManager = new MQQueueManager(mqQueueManagerName, sslQueueProperties);
```

Comment: With MQ v9.2 SSL is supported in managed mode(Managed client).What error do you see in the queue manager error logs?

Comment: Show example code that is failing.

Comment: @JoshMc:Thanks, I have added my failed code.

Comment: @subbaraoc: I faced 2538: MQRC_HOST_NOT_AVAILABLE error

Comment: `MQRC_HOST_NOT_AVAILABLE` is a client side error,  @subbaraoc asked "What error do you see in the **queue manager** error logs?"  What is `certStore` set to.

Comment: I am having the same problem, no errors in the log @JoshMC

Comment: @WilkovanderVeen, What specific version of mq client dll are you using?

Comment: @JoshMc ibmmqdotnetclient.9.2.3 (.NET Standard)

Comment: @WilkovanderVeen I see you had another question about a previous error that Morag answered.   You should accept her answer and open a new question about this error.

Comment: @JoshMC you are right. I am going to do so.